# Linguistic cases / declination and gettext

Tags: translation, multilingual, gettext

Has anybody ever thought about gettext and different cases in some languages. We are currently having the problem that in Croatian even names are declined.

### example

- English: About Foobar
- German: Über Foobar
- Croatian: O Foobaru (mark the **u**)

I am using gettext to insert this name flexible as it might change:

```
translate('About %s', name)
```

What are the best methods to allow declination here? In case of **Foobar** and Croatian declination you could solve it like this:

```
About %s => O %su
```

But now let’s use a word word ending in **a** like **Foobara**, then the Croatian correct grammar would be **O Foobari** (the **a** has to be removed and an **i** attached).

How can I overcome this shortage of gettext?

Answer (score 1):

gettext does not support such declension.

If you know every possible candidates for %s, you may list all of them in resource, like,

```
msgid "About Foobar"
msgstr "O Foobaru"
msgid "About Bazbar"
msgstr "O Bazbarbaru"
msgid "About Foobara"
msgstr "O Foobari"
msgid "About Bazbara"
msgstr "O Bazbari"
```

but then it will make other language like German cumbersome.

Or, if you can define that Croatian declension as a function, you may process it first in your function and keep using the generic gettext conversion.

```
translate('About %s', myDeclension(name));
```

and the myDeclension function does this,

```
function myDeclension(text) {
  if (isLocale() != 'hr') { return text; }
  if (isEndWithA(text)) { return replaceLastAWithI(text); }
  else { return addTrailingU(text); }
  // add more Croatian specific conversion if any
}
```